# Way to effectively call _BitScanReverse or __builtin_clz in constexpr functions?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, constexpr, intrinsics

It seems that _BitScanReverse, despite being an intrinsic and not a real function, can't be called in a constexpr function in Visual C++.  I'm aware that I can implement this operation myself in a much slower way, which would be fine for the case where it's evaluated at compile-time but it's unfortunate that it wouldn't just be the 1-clock-cycle, single CPU instruction (BSR) for the case where it's evaluated at run-time.  I haven't tried __builtin_clz in GCC/Clang yet, but it might or might not have the same sort of issue, and I want this code to work across the major compilers, (with a slow fallback for non-GCC, non-Clang, non-VC compilers).

Ideas/Questions:

Is there an easy way to have a function use one block of code when evaluating at compile-time, so that it can be constexpr-safe, and a different block of code for run-time, so that it can be fast?  (If so, this would also be relevant to a few other questions I have.)

Alternatively, is there a way to trick the compiler into being able to evaluate _BitScanReverse for constexpr code?

Side question:

Is there any word of plans to eventually add this to the C++ standard?  They've added std::log2 and std::ilogb, but those both go through floating-point numbers, instead of just doing one BSR, (or CLZ and a subtraction on ARM chips).

Comment: I think with GCC-compatible compilers, you can use `__builtin_constant_p`. Unfortunately, I don't know whether msvc has a similar construct.

Comment: @geza Yeah, when searching, I found a commit in the Qt codebase where they removed constexpr from some functions, citing `_BitScanForward` as the reason, and they had equivalent functions using `__builtin_clz` on GCC, so I figured they're probably okay for constexpr.  However, it wasn't explicitly stated there, and they removed constexpr from those functions as well, but possibly just for self-consistency across compilers.

Comment: This is why languages need to get new standardized portable ways to express things that hardware can do efficiently.  Rust has `foo.leading_zeros()` for primitive types like `i32`.  It's disappointing that C and C++ haven't kept up and still don't have standard bit-scan or popcnt functions.  There's POSIX `ffs()` find first set (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ffs.3.html), but it's just POSIX not ISO C or C++.  Some compilers do recognize certain idioms, so you can sometimes write what looks like a dumb loop and have it compile to a `popcnt` instruction, but IDK about bit-scan.

Comment: Yes, `__builtin_clz` is accepted in a `constexpr` function in gcc, with no warning even with `-Wextra -Wpedantic`.  https://godbolt.org/g/6cai3A.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for checking `__builtin_clz`!  I might try out that website you linked to for other things, if it's free to try.  Regarding the C/C++ standards, I've been there so many times.  I'm particularly disappointed that the Javascript standard is going to add SSE-like support before C or C++, though at least GCC added support for the Intel standard intrinsics for SSE instructions a few years ago, so that Visual C++ and GCC can use the same intrinsics there.

Comment: Matt Godbolt makes his compiler-explorer site available to everyone free of charge.  It's pretty useful because he has MSVC, ICC, and nightly builds of the latest gcc and clang for x86-64.  He also has MIPS, ARM, ARM64, and some other non-x86 gcc set up.  Also, the code behind that site is open source; see the github link in the top right.

Comment: re: SSE.  Most simple stuff can auto-vectorize fairly decently in C and C++, because ahead-of-time compilers can take the time to do that.  Javascript is always JIT-compiled or interpreted, so it makes more sense to need manual vectorization even for simple stuff.  If you need to vectorize manually in C++, often you need some shuffling or other stuff that isn't universally available across different SIMD architectures (SSE2 doesn't even have any variable-control shuffles).   Or you didn't use `__restrict__`, which ISO C++ doesn't have, even though C has had it since C99.

Comment: It would make some sense for ISO C++ to standardize some basic SIMD support, like GNU C vector stuff ([`int __attribute__(( vector_size(16) ))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html)).  But there is already OpenMP (`#pragma omp simd` before a loop) to ask explicitly for auto-vectorization (without having to use `-ffast-math`).

Comment: (Sorry for going off-topic.) Some simple to vectorize cases are slowly getting supported, thankfully, but it seems most cases with conditions have to be explicitly vectorized, and float/int bit tricks just confuse the compiler.  I don't blame compiler writers for the tough stuff, though, since it's a bit like expecting the compiler to change bubble sort to quicksort; it's unlikely to ever happen, and if it does, it's questionable whether it should override the programmer's choice in that way.

Comment: @PeterCordes C/C++ does not even have a way method to provide the programmer add with carry `adc` which has been available since before 1980 for x86.

Comment: @Zboson At least that can easily be emulated.

Answer (score 2):

For `C++20` you can use `std::bit_width` and others form [`<bit>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/bit) header

```
template< class T >
constexpr T bit_width(T x) noexcept;
```

```
#include <bit>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using BitArray = std::array<unsigned, 8>;

constexpr BitArray Bits() {
    BitArray bits;
    for (unsigned x{0}; x != 8; ++x)
      bits[x] = std::bit_width(x);
    return bits;
}

auto main() -> int {
    constexpr BitArray bits = Bits();

    for (unsigned x{0}; x != 8; ++x) {
        std::cout
            << "bit_width( "
            << std::bitset<4>{x} << " ) = "
            << bits[x] << " "
            << std::bit_width(x) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Try it on [Godbolt](https://#include%20%3Cbit%3E%20#include%20%3Cbitset%3E%20#include%20%3Ciostream%3E%20#include%20%3Carray%3E%20%20using%20BitArray%20=%20std::array%3Cunsigned,%208%3E;%20%20constexpr%20BitArray%20Bits()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20BitArray%20bits;%20%20%20%20%20for%20(unsigned%20x%7B0%7D;%20x%20!=%208;%20++x)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bits%5Bx%5D%20=%20std::bit_width(x);%20%20%20%20%20return%20bits;%20%7D%20%20auto%20main()%20-%3E%20int%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20constexpr%20BitArray%20bits%20=%20Bits();%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(unsigned%20x%7B0%7D;%20x%20!=%208;%20++x)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20std::cout%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%3C%20%22bit_width(%20%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%3C%20std::bitset%3C4%3E%7Bx%7D%20%3C%3C%20%22%20)%20=%20%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%3C%20bits%5Bx%5D%20%3C%3C%20%22%20%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%3C%20std::bit_width(x)%20%3C%3C%20%27%5Cn%27;%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%7D)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an easy way to have a function use one block of code when evaluating at compile-time, so that it can be constexpr-safe, and a different block of code for run-time, so that it can be fast? (If so, this would also be relevant to a few other questions I have.)

As of C++20, yes! [std::is_constant_evaluated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated) serves that exact purpose.

So you can now do:

```
#include <type_traits>

constexpr bool my_bitscan_reverse(unsigned long& index, unsigned long mask) {
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
        // do it in a constexpr-friendly manner
        // who cares if it's not as fast as possible
    } else {
        return _BitScanReverse(&index, mask);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function can compute reverse bit scan at compile time:

```
constexpr int bit_scan_reverse_const(uint64_t const n) {
    if (n == 0) return -1;
    uint64_t a = n, b = 0, j = 64, k = 0;
    do {
        j >>= 1;
        k = (uint64_t)1 << j;
        if (a >= k) {
            a >>= j;
            b += j;
        }
    } while (j > 0);
    return int(b);
}
```

(from vector class library https://github.com/vectorclass/version2/blob/master/instrset.h )